# Join two tables where both joined columns have a large set of different values

Tags: t-sql

I am currently trying to join two tables, where both of the tables have very many different in the columns I am joining.

Here's the tsql

```
from AVG(Position) as Position from MonitoringGsc_Keywords as sk
Join GSC_RankingData on sk.Id = GSC_RankingData.KeywordId
groupy by sk.Id
```

The execution plan shows me, that it takes very much time to perform the join. I think it is because a huge group from the first table has to be compared with a huge group of values in the second table.

- MonitoringGsc_Keywords.Id has about 60.000 different values
- GSC_RankingData hat about 100.000.000 Values

MonitoringGsc_Keywords.Id is Primary-Key of MonitoringGsc_Keywords   GSC_RankingData.KeywordId is indexed.

So, what can i do to increase performance?

Comment: That does not look like valid TSQL to me.  You have two from.  "from AVG(Position) as Position from MonitoringGsc_Keywords as sk"

Answer (score 0):

1. Is Position column from GSC_RankingData table? If yes then JOIN is redundant and query should looks like this:

   SELECT AVG(rd.Position) as Position 
   FROM GSC_RankingData rd
   GROUP BY rd.KeywordId;
2. If Position column is in GSC_RankingData table then index on GSC_RankingData should include this column and looks like this:

   CREATE INDEX IX_GSC_RankingData_KeywordId_Position ON GSC_RankingData(KeywordId) INCLUDE(Position);
3. You should check indexes fragmentation for this tables, to do this you could use this query:

   `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(), object_id('MonitoringGsc_Keywords'), null, null, 'DETAILED')`

if avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 5% and < 30% then

```
ALTER INDEX [index name] on [table name] REORGANIZE;
```

if avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 30% then

```
ALTER INDEX [index name] on [table name] REBUILD;
```

4. It could be problem with statistics, you could check it with query:

   SELECT
   sp.stats_id, name, filter_definition, last_updated, rows, rows_sampled, 
   steps, unfiltered_rows, modification_counter 
   FROM sys.stats AS stat 
   CROSS APPLY sys.dm_db_stats_properties(stat.object_id, stat.stats_id) AS sp
   WHERE stat.object_id = object_id('GSC_RankingData');

check last update date, rows count, if it not be current then update statistics. Also it could be possible that statistics not exist, then you must create it.